# Hiding the column in gridview for dynamically created datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a datatable dynamically, means my datatable column fields could be different based on the columns returned by stored procedure. When I am returning data using stored procedure, I need to return "ID" field compulsorily. But I dont want to show this "ID" field in the gridview when I bind the datatable to gridview.
How to make this "ID" field hidden for gridview display?

Comment: @Blachshma [are you sure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23326/148672)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the autogenerate columns property of the gridview to false and then bind this datatable to the gridview.